# Jupyter Notebook Output window in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

does anyone know how to change the font-size of Jupyter notebook output window in Visual studio code? After the update of VS Code it is too big.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`notebook.outputFontSize` seems to be the config you're looking for.
Description from the [VS Code settings documentations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> Font size for the output text for notebook cells. When set to 0 `editor.fontSize` is used.